# Question about ‘this’ inside higher-order-function's callback

Tags: javascript, callback, this, higher-order-functions

I have a question regarding ‘this’ in JavaScript higher-order-function's callback.

I've been exploring the following code - the goal is conversion of a function that accepts a callback into a function returning a promise. 
Source: https://javascript.info/promisify

A function that accepts a callback:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;

  script.onload = () => callback(null, script);
  script.onerror = () => callback(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));

  document.head.append(script);
}
```

Now, the author uses a higher-order-function that will accept the stated above function as a callback and do the promisification:

```
function promisify(f) {
  return function (...args) { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      function callback(err, result) { 
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }

      args.push(callback); 

      f.call(this, ...args); 
    });
  };
};

// usage:

let loadScriptPromise = promisify(loadScript);
loadScriptPromise('path/script.js').then(...);
```

The thing that I don't understand is:

Why do we call the f function in this way:
**f.call(this, ...args);** ?

What will ‘this’ be in this case?
Why can't we just call it like this: **f(...args);** ?

I know that in order to track down what a callback’s ‘this’ is pointing to, you need to inspect the higher order function enclosing it...
But I can't get why in this case do we have to state the callback’s ‘this’ explicitly?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we call the f function in this way: `f.call(this, ...args);` ?
>
> What will ‘this’ be in this case? Why can't we just call it like this: `f(...args);` ?

Let me answer the *What will ‘this’ be in this case?* part first:

We don't know (in general) and that is why `.call` is used, but I will get to that.

`promisify` is supposed to "seamlessly" wrap an existing function. That means that calling either `f` or `promisify(f)` should return the same result.

The value of `this` depends on **how** a function is **called**. `promisify` can't know how the new wrapper function is going to be called, nor does it know whether the wrapped function uses `this` or not. Therefore it needs to assume that `this` is going to be significant and has to call the wrapped function in a way that sets `this` correctly.
The only way to call a function and explicitly set the `this` value is via `.call` or `.apply`. If the function was called as `f(...args)` then `this` inside `f` would either be the global object or `undefined`.

Here is a simpler wrapper function that demonstrates the issue:

```js
function wrapWithThis(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    f.call(this, ...args);
  }
}

function wrapWithoutThis(f) {
  return function(...args) {
    f(...args);
  }
}

function wrapMe() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}

const obj = {
  foo: 42,
  withThis: wrapWithThis(wrapMe),
  withoutThis: wrapWithoutThis(wrapMe),
};

obj.withThis();
obj.withoutThis();
```

---

Having said all that, specific to  your example, given that `loadScript` doesn't use `this`, it wouldn't make a difference if `f.call(this, ...)` or `f(...)` was used.